# What are the best practices setting file permissions for a PHP website on Apache2/Linux (LAMP)?

Tags: php, linux, wordpress, apache, security

What is the minimum permissions to set the site files to, in order to allow apache2/php to execute code, show html/css/js, and for some files update settings download and install plugins.

The websites I am building are either Drupal or Wordpress.

I'd like to set permissions so that `www-data` has the minimum permissions and the admin (which is me for now) has permissions to allow him to do tasks from an SSH session without needing `sudo`.

[Edit]
I'd like to add that I have full access to the LAMP server via SSH. What I am after is the most restrictive and hence the most secure way to set user and group permissions, so in short:

- What group
- What owner
- What permissions

For all site files for say a wordpress
In order to achieve

- Apache can access the files and execute PHP
- For some special files or folders the Wordpress should be able to change
- The admin can easily change files without having to use sudo

Answer (score 1):

Mostly the directory should have the permission set to 755. If you set it to 777 then the files can be written there. Files should be, at most, 664. If you use the WP editor, you might need these files to be 666 but you really should revert them back to 664 after making any changes. Never specify files greater than 666 unless specified.

Some hosting only allow uploads on 777 permission only avoid such and try contacting hosting for this.

See at https://codex.wordpress.org/Changing_File_Permissions

Comment: I think the link is a little helpful, I've edited the question to add more details about what I am after